# Grouping Table Rows

Tags: tables, matrices, tabularray, xtable

I'm trying to incorporate groups row-wise for my following table:

[image]

The current version is achieved with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}   % needed
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\NewTableCommand\TB{\textbullet}
\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\footnotesize{Number and Stability of Systems}}    % from makecell
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1} = 1pt,
                 hline{2-19}=solid,
                 hline{18} = 1pt,
                 vlines,
                 colspec = {>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} *{13}{c}}, 
                 cell{2}{2-14} = {cmd=\rotcell},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                }
    \SetCell[r=2]{f, font=\bfseries}    Articles
        &   \SetCell[c=13]{c}   Characteristics
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
        & \footnotesize{Execution Frequency}
            & \footnotesize{Execution Time}
                & \footnotesize{Maturity}
                    & \footnotesize{Determinism}
                        & \footnotesize{Standardization}
                            & \footnotesize{Machine-Readable Data}
                                & \footnotesize{Human Involvement}
                                    & \footnotesize{Proneness to Human Error}
                                        & \footnotesize{Business Impact}
                                            & \footnotesize{Number and Stability of Systems}
                                                & \footnotesize{Compliance and Security} & \footnotesize{End of Life} & \footnotesize{Automation in other Systems} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Choi2021}}}
        & \TB   & \TB  
                & 
                    &   &   &   &   
                                    & 
                                        & 
                                            &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Agostinelli2021}}}
        & \TB 
            &   & 
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Leno2020a}}}
        & \TB 
            &  
                & 
                    &   &   &   
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Gao2019}}}
        & \TB 
            &  
                & 
                    &   &   &   
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Rhouati2021}}}
        & \TB 
            &  
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  &   & \TB  
                                & \TB  &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Lacity2016}}}
        & \TB 
            & \TB  
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  & \TB   &   
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Leshob2018}}}
        & \TB 
            & \TB
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  & \TB   &   
                                & \TB   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{wanner2019process}}}
        & \TB 
            &  \TB
                & \TB 
                    &   & \TB   &   
                                & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Wellmann2020}}}
        & \TB 
            &  \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB  
                                & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Padmini2021}}}
        & \TB 
            & \TB 
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  &   &  \TB 
                                &   & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   & \TB  &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Viehhauser2021}}}
        & \TB 
            &  
                & \TB 
                    &   & \TB  & \TB   
                                & \TB  & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Plattfaut2020}}}
        & \TB 
            & \TB  
                &  
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB  
                                &   & \TB   & \TB   & \TB   &   &   & \TB      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{ChristianLangmann2021}}}
        & \TB 
            &  \TB
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  & \TB  &  \TB 
                                & \TB  &   &   & \TB   & \TB   &   &       \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|m|}{\footnotesize\textsc{\cite[]{Smeets2019}}}
        & \TB 
            & \TB 
                & \TB 
                    & \TB  &   & \TB  
                                &   &   & \TB   &   &   &   &       \\
    \textbf{Total}
        &  14
            & 9 
                & 9
                    & 8 & 7  & 7  
                                & 6  & 5  & 4  & 4   & 2  & 1  &   1   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to group the table rows into several groups (similar to the grouping of the columns into "characteristics"). Sth. that looks like the follow .ppt sketch:

[image]

Can you help with that one?

Many thanks in advance for tips!

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete document (as is provided in my answer from where you take a code). People don't know, how is `\TB` defined ,

Comment: thanks for the hint - I did change it accordingly.

Comment: also add packages needed for  `\citet{...}`.

Comment: I removed the use of citet, included \cite[] instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

**Edit:**
As far as I see, your table can fit on page also when is used `small` font size. Also, table is more consistent, if this size is used in whole table:

You need to add one column, and in used cells in the first column add `cmd=\rotcell[cc]`. A bit more care is with table rules. See MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}   % needed
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \small
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\footnotesize{Number and Stability of Systems}}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = {2-Z}{1pt},
             hline{2} = {3-Z}{solid},
             hline{3} = 0.6pt,  
             hline{4-Y}=solid, 
             vline{1} = {3-Y}{solid},
             vline{2-Z},
             colspec = {c Q[l,font=\scshape] *{11}{c}},
             cell{3-Z}{1} = {cmd=\rotcell[cc]},
             cell{2}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotcell},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             vspan = even
            }
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{f, font=\bfseries}    Articles
        &   \SetCell[c=11]{c}   Characteristic
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   &   Execution Frequency
            &   Execution Time
                &   Maturity
                    &   Determinism
                        &   Standardization
                            &   Machine-Readable Data
                                &   Human Involvement
                                    &   Proneness to Human Error
                                        &   Business Impact
                                            &   Number and Stability of Systems
                                                &   Compliance and Security
                                                    &   End of Life
                                                        &   Automation in other Systems \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    Group 1                                               
    &   \citet{Choi2021}
        & \TB   & \TB
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Agostinelli2021}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Leno2020a}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Gao2019}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    Group 2
    &   \citet{Rhouati2021}
        & \TB
            &   & \TB
                    & \TB  &   & \TB
                                & \TB  &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Lacity2016}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB   
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Leshob2018} 
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB   
                                &   & \TB   
                                        &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{wanner2019process} 
    & \TB
        &  \TB
            & \TB
                &   & \TB   &
                            & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    Group 3
    &   \citet{Wellmann2020}
        & \TB
            &  \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB
                                & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Padmini2021}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  &   &  \TB
                                &   & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   & \TB  &       \\
    &   \citet{Viehhauser2021}
        & \TB
            &
                & \TB
                    &   & \TB  & \TB
                                & \TB  & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \citet{Plattfaut2020}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                &
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB
                                &   & \TB   & \TB   & \TB   &   &   & \TB      \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Group 4
    &   \citet{ChristianLangmann2021}
        & \TB
            &  \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB  &  \TB
                                & \TB  &   &   & \TB   & \TB   &   &       \\
&   \citet{Smeets2019}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  &   & \TB
                                &   &   & \TB   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textbf{Total}
        &  14
            & 9
                & 9
                    & 8 & 7  & 7
                                & 6  & 5  & 4  & 4   & 2  & 1  &   1   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- don't mix syntax of `tabularray` and other tables' packages
- package `tabularray` from version 2022A doesn't support commands `multirow` and `\multicolumn`
- it is sensible to move cells' contents formation to table preamble (as is done in above MWE)
- Since bibliography as well used packages for it are not know, command `\citet` are undefined. Consequently compilation of MWE had to be forced that you will get showed result.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works for me now!

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. For the rows, you give the number of *logical* rows (and not the number of physical lines as with `\multicolumn`).

With the key `hvlines`, all the rules are drawn, excepted in the blocks (constructed by `\Block`) and in the corners (specified by the key `corners`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{cl*{13}{c}}[corners,hvlines,cell-space-limits=6pt]
    &   \Block{2-1}{}
        & \Block{1-*}{\textbf{Characteristic}} \\
    & \textbf{Articles}  
        &   \RowStyle{\rotate}
            Execution Frequency
            &   Execution Time
                &   Maturity
                    &   Determinism
                        &   Standardization
                            &   Machine-Readable Data
                                &   Human Involvement
                                    &   Proneness to Human Error
                                        &   Business Impact
                                            &   Number and Stability of Systems
                                                &   Compliance and Security
                                                    &   End of Life
                                                        &   Automation in other Systems \\
\Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Group 1}
    &   \textsc{Choi2021}
        & \TB   & \TB
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Agostinelli2021}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Leno2020a}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Gao2019}
        & \TB
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Group 2}
    &   \textsc{Rhouati2021}
        & \TB
            &   & \TB
                    & \TB  &   & \TB
                                & \TB  &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Lacity2016}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB   
                                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Leshob2018} 
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB   
                                &   & \TB   
                                        &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{wanner2019process} 
    & \TB
        &  \TB
            & \TB
                &   & \TB   &
                            & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Group 3}
    &   \textsc{Wellmann2020}
        & \TB
            &  \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB
                                & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Padmini2021}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  &   &  \TB
                                &   & \TB   & \TB  & \TB   & \TB   & \TB  &       \\
    &   \textsc{Viehhauser2021}
        & \TB
            &
                & \TB
                    &   & \TB  & \TB
                                & \TB  & \TB   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textsc{Plattfaut2020}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                &
                    & \TB  & \TB  & \TB
                                &   & \TB   & \TB   & \TB   &   &   & \TB      \\
\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{Group 4}
    &   \textsc{ChristianLangmann2021}
        & \TB
            &  \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  & \TB  &  \TB
                                & \TB  &   &   & \TB   & \TB   &   &       \\
&   \textsc{Smeets2019}
        & \TB
            & \TB
                & \TB
                    & \TB  &   & \TB
                                &   &   & \TB   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   \textbf{Total}
        &  14
            & 9
                & 9
                    & 8 & 7  & 7
                                & 6  & 5  & 4  & 4   & 2  & 1  &   1   \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]